# Rectangular paper fold

Tags: geometry

> Given: A rectangular piece of paper $ABCD$ with $AB = 8$ and $AD = 12$. Fold the paper such that $B$ coincides with $D$. Find the length of the fold. *(AoPS)*

My work: I first made a parallelogram like below and found some relationships with the Pythagorean theorem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on *which* parallelogram you select from
all possible parallelograms that look like your picture,
you *might* find that when you fold the paper so that $B$ touches $D$,
the parallelogram is folded neatly into a triangle.

That can happen only if you choose the other two corners of the parallelogram
so that they lie on the line where the paper must be folded.
Put the other two corners anywhere else, and you'll be 
folding them over parts of the parallelogram that don't match up.

If you do manage to fold the parallelogram into a triangle, that tells you
something about the lengths of adjacent sides of the parallelogram.
Put that information into your Pythagorean formula for the triangle
along edge $CD$.

It looks like you did this successfully!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Observe that the fold is made along the perpendicular bisector of $BD$, as $B$ and $D$ must be equally distant from it.

Answer (score 0):

Since $AoPS$ is not marked, I assume you want to verify $x$ at first.

Draw lines with center of paper as the origin.

Equation of Diagonal $BD$  is:

$$ y = \frac{8 x}{12} = \frac{2x}{3} $$

The perpendicular bisector of $BD$ is the Fold. Its equation is ( slope is its negative  reciprocal).

$$ y = \frac{-3 x}{2}  $$

You want to find where it cuts $ y= -4. $

Solve them to get  $$ x = \frac{8}{3}. $$

The portion you marked as $x$ is $ 6-\dfrac{8}{3 }= \dfrac{10}{3},\; $ OK!

*Generalization:*

It is possible by above method to get x for a rectangular sheet of paper width $W$ and length $L$, $ L> W $.

By the same procedure

$$ \dfrac {W}{2}=\dfrac{L\, x}{W}   $$

$$ x_1 =\dfrac{L ^2 + W^2}{2 L } ,\;  x_2 =\dfrac{L ^2 - W^2}{2 L } $$

These can be verified on say, a sheet of paper. If diagonal =D,

$$ x_1 = D^2/(2 L) $$

and

$$ x_2 = 0 $$ for square paper.